# how to make a big image to be not drawn to height we want in bootstarp4

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-cards

i want to make a big image like a [cards in bootstrap (Image overlays)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#using-grid-markup) but image is too big and the height i want ..this is i have done :[image]

html :

```
<section class="card bg-dark no-border">
        <div class="flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center bg-danger text-dark">
            <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="img/bg_1.jpg" alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-img-overlay text-center m-auto">
                <h5 class="card-title mt-3">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
                    content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and does any one know a better way to make texts center with flex ?? .. im useing margin for this but it would be nicer way to do this flex box ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this for a big image to show in web page ,I write my own class to make this happen :

CSS :

```
<style>
.proposal{
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1020/200/nature/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container-fluid proposal justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-row  justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5">
            <p class="text-center text-sm-left">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab blanditiis cupiditate deleniti dignissimos dolorem doloremque, illo laborum, libero, nesciunt odit qui sit veritatis? Atque illum iusto maxime, nulla optio saepe?
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="visit_time">btn</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you just a picture with a bad resolution

Comment: nope .. the image itself  is good .. my problem is the height using css  and bootstrap and in full width of viewport displays like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please prefer flexbox documentation first but for your problem, I give you a solution.

Just add `d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center` on your text block and for showing text purpose I highlight it with `text-danger`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section class="card bg-dark no-border">
    <div class="bg-danger text-dark">
        <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/bird_silhouette_vector_134154_1920x1080.jpg" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-img-overlay text-center m-auto d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center text-danger">
            <h5 class="card-title mt-3">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
                content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank for your time .. but my problem is how to make this big img responsive with a height we want .. which is smaller than images height .. like 200px in other words `<img src='big_img.jpg' style='hight : 200px;'>` .. how to solve this ?

Comment: nice centering btw